# How do I filter CDATA out and only get the text from HTML?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to parse a HTML file using Nokogiri. I am able to do that but I only want text and no CDATA or JavaScript, since my script and div tags are all over the file.

Comment: Could you show an example of the data you have and the data you want to get using Nokogiri?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all script elements,

```
doc.search('script').remove
```

… and then select all text elements

```
doc.xpath('//text()')
```

… or just select the text elements within div elements

```
doc.xpath('//div//text()')
```